# コントローラの役割は基本的にはJSPにはやらせないですよね？

Tags: java

コントローラの役割を、HttpServletだけでなくjspにやらせる構成も
正しい思想の１つなのでしょうか？？

.
◆コントローラ
「コントローラ」は、
基本「依頼と、依頼結果をもとにした次の依頼」をする。
という風に役割を捉えていました。

例えば
Ａに処理依頼をしたあと、
処理が成功したから今度はＢに処理依頼をして、
その結果データが
１件以上だったらＣに依頼をして、
０件だったら次はＤに処理を依頼する。
のような。

そして、それはHttpServletのところにやらせるものなのかと捉えています。
（※間違っているのかもですが。。）

合っていますでしょうか？

.
◆特例と思っていること（サーブレットなしのケース）
書こうと思えば、サーブレットを撤廃して、
画面遷移は、x.jsp ⇒ y.jsp ⇒ z.jsp
と、サーブレットを介さずにチェーンを作ることも可能だと思います。
制御がほとんど内場合、サーブレットを作らず
薄いコントローラ部分をJSPに寄せることもあるのかもしれません。

しかし、大抵の場合、
①Exeptionのハンドリングや
②セッション変数への伝播値のセット
があるかと思います。
そういう部分があったとしても、
JSPとして書くという方針も、わりと一般的なのでしょうか？

.
◆なぜ自分がコントローラをサーブレットに担当させたいか？

jspになんでもやらせすぎると、JSPの各ソース行が、

Ａ：プレゼンテーション層としての処理なのか？
　（イテレータでの描画とか）

Ｂ：ファンクション層の処理なのか？
　（例えば入力チェック処理など）

Ｃ：コントローラ層の処理なのか？
　（各結果を元に、次にどこの処理に
　　どういうデリゲートするのか等処理）

が分かりにくく、カオスなソースになると思っています。
そんな風になるくらいだったら、
コントローラはサーブレットにさせた方が良いと思うのですが、あえて全てJSPにさせるメリットもあったりするのでしょうか？
,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はい、少なくとも私は普通はやらせません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分の認識に少しだけ自信がもてました。（たぶん、色んな考え方があるのかもですね。。）